# SQL query to filter data with 3 optional Parameter on same Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Suppose My table has a column ProfileID & i want to filter with ProfileID.
In stored procedure i am sending @PageID, @GroupID, @ChannelID **(all 3 parameters are optional, if not sent then these value will be 0 by default)** to fileter out the data which are actually ProfileID.So actually i want to filter data with **WHERE ProfileID IN(@PageID,@GroupID,@ChannelID )** but if all 3 parameters are 0 then i won't filter anything.I would filter if & only if atleast 1 paramters is >0

TABLE STRUCTURE

```
+--------+-----------------+---------------------+
| PostID | PostDescription | PostType  ProfileID |
+--------+-----------------+---------------------+
|  25151 | Messed up       | S         117       |
|  25152 | Messed up       | S         116       |
|  25153 | Messed up       | S         119       |
|  25154 | Messed up       | S         11        |
|  25155 | Messed up       | S         16        |
|  25157 | Messed up       | S         23        |
|  25158 | Messed up       | S         22        |
|  25159 | Messed up       | S         7         |
|        |                 |                     |
+--------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

### Example Case

1. @PageID=117 ,@GroupID=116 , @ChannelID=16 should return rows with profileID 
   IN(117,116,16)
2. @PageID=0 ,@GroupID=0, @ChannelID=11 should return rows with profileID =11
3. @PageID=117,@GroupID=0, @ChannelID=11 should return rows with profileID IN(117,11)
4. @PageID=0,@GroupID=0, @ChannelID=0 should return all rows without filtering.

How can i achieve this with  WHERE condition ?

Comment: You can use the `CASE` construct for this.

Comment: Add all these parameters and check if its more than 0 in where clause

Comment: I guess they all are int data types, so where @PageID+@GroupID+@ChannelID>0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an `or`:

```
WHERE ProfileID IN(@PageID,@GroupID,@ChannelID )
   OR COALESCE(@PageID,@GroupID,@ChannelID) is null
```

Above if parameters are null, if they are `0`:

```
WHERE ProfileID IN(@PageID,@GroupID,@ChannelID )
   OR (@PageID = 0 AND @GroupID = 0 AND @ChannelID = 0)
```

Comment: Its 0 not NULL. Thanks its working i think.Ops it was so easy but i was so confused what to do. lol.